# Can't get node of firebase children

Tags: swift, firebase

Hi there i'm newest in swift. I am working with a firebase database with at 2 layer of hierarchy as well as many children for each node. I got 1st layer (descript, enddata and other), but i stll can't get the news node. Is in 3 to 5 random keys. I sow many issues but still not have issue for me.

I'm understand i'm doing some wrong but what?

The Firebase is:

[image]

i need retreat the news child

struct is

```
struct ICONews {
    let ICOId: String
    let news1: String
    let news2: String
    let news3: String
    init?(ICOId: String, dict: [String: Any] ) {
        self.ICOId=ICOId
        guard let news1 = dict[""] as? String,
        let news2 = dict[""] as? String,
        let news3 = dict[""] as? String
         else { return nil }
        self.news1 = news1
        self.news2 = news2
        self.news3 = news3
    }
}

struct NewsSnapShot {
    let posts: [ICONews]
        init?(with snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
         var posts = [ICONews] ()
            guard let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: Any]] else { return nil }
            for snap in snapDict {
                guard let post = ICONews (ICOId: snap.key, dict: snap.value) else {continue}
                posts.append(post)
            }
            self.posts=posts
    }
}
```

class of DataBase

```
class DatabaseService {
    static let shared = DatabaseService()
    private init(){}
    let ICOReference = Database.database().reference()
}
```

and retreat method

```
DatabaseService.shared.ICOReference.child("news").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let postsSnapShot = ICOSnapShot(with: snapshot) else {return}    
})
```

Comment: i trying do like this but

Comment: your node "-KtqP2YmNO2FjIW5DiPT" is because of auto id, you can make it by static text as base node. Or dynamic node which you can track. like numbers.

Answer (score 1):

done

```
Database.database().reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
let enumerator = snapshot.children
while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
    let values = (rest as! DataSnapshot).value as? NSDictionary
        let enumeratorMap1 = (rest as! DataSnapshot).children
        while let rest2 = enumeratorMap1.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            let valuesMap1 = (rest2 as! DataSnapshot).value as? NSDictionary
            if (rest2 as! DataSnapshot).key == "news" {
                print(rest2.value)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the the Firebase Api call like

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    let receivedMessage = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

                    let name = receivedMessage["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let id = receivedMessage["id"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let profileurl = receivedMessage["url"] as? String ?? ""

                    completion(User(name: name, id: id, url: url))
                } else {
                    failure()
                }
})
```

Comment: actually i don't know child("users"). in my base its named like "-KtqP2YmNO2FjIW5DiPT"

Comment: This is the auto incremented value created by fire base, So you can save this id on the model

Comment: but how? can a small example?

Comment: Search for quick chat  GitHub and you will got all of your answer

Comment: Thanks, i found it, but it's too complicated for me. I found the way, but it's not right. I well do snapshot with auto inc value everytime when i need the news